# Prevent Javascript from Overriding CSS

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox

I made a gallery page where you can look at pictures fullscreen when you click on them using lightbox.
In my footer is: lightbox-plus-jquery.js from https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
I wrote CSS that does what I want it too.
But if you look at my website https://rocallisa.xyz/photos
The width and height in the lightbox get overriden.

```
.lb-outercontainer{
    height: 90vh !important;
    width: 97vw !important;
}

.lightbox.lb-image{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    max-height: 90vh !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    object-fit: contain;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 4px solid white;
}
```

What I want:
[image: what I want]
What I get:
[image: What I get]

Comment: change the order of css `.lb-outercontainer` after `.lightbox.lb-image`

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if that what u means but your `width` and `height` are getting override by your `!important`.

[image]

Just removing it could solve the problem, try not to use `!important` if possible.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: That does look better but I want the white container to stay the same size at all times and the picture to stretch, and fill the width or height.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
.lightbox.lb-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    ...
}
```

Using `object-fit: contain` at the `img` tag with a `width: 100%` could be what you are looking for. I cannot post image anymore cause of my reputation loss so it post a link to the image.

[Lightbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQVt.jpg)

Comment: There is no `object-fit: contain;` in your CSS file `lightbox.css`. You are maybe not updating the site. The file is not uploading into your site correctly. Link: https://imgur.com/a/Oy6AR7F